# Isotope Metafizzy: How to check if an element has already been initialized as an isotope container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

The plugin: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

I would like to be able to check if an element has already been initialized as an isotope container. EG the follow code will result in an error message if the element has not:

```
 $(".div-class").isotope('destroy')
```

Yields:

```
 cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'
```

I would like to be able to write something like:

```
 if ($(".div-class").isotope('already-initialized')) {
     // some other code
 }
```

I can't find such a method on isotope docs yet. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I notice this plugin would add a `isotope` class to the container, you can try this code:

```
if ($(".div-class").hasClass('isotope')) {
 // some other code
}
```

Comment: ahhh... sometimes, the most obvious answer eludes me.. thanks!

Comment: This might have worked in the past, but when I initialize my container, it doesn't add any class.

Comment: The answer by user2625495 is the correct way to do it with the current version of Isotope. (v2.0.1)

Comment: the user formerly known as user2625495 here. I changed my name because  user2625495 didn't seem to stick for some reason.

Answer (score 25):

That class is no longer added by isotope. I solved it like this:

```
if($(".div-class").data('isotope')) {

}
```